# Is average on a set of numbers (no duplicates allowed) meaningful?

Tags: statistics, average

Is it meaningful to do a average operation on a set of numbers ??

By set, I mean something which will not have duplicate elements.

Let us assume that a car travels at 1 Km/hr for one hour, 4 Km/hr for next hour and then again at 1 Km/hr for the third hour. Average speed is  is (1 + 4 + 1)/3 = 2 Km/hr. **This means that, the kind of travelling that the person did (as mentioned above) is equivalent to travelling at travelling at a constant speed of 2 Km/hr for 3 continuous hours**.

Now in another case, let us remove the duplicate elements while calculating the average. So new average is (1 + 4)/2 = 2.5 Km/hr.... I guess this number 2.5 Km/hr has no real world meaning. No one can make use of this value in any algorithm or other way to understand or analyse systems. Am I right??

This act of removing duplicates while calculating the average of any group of numbers is not going to result in a meaningful answer for any physical quantity(not just with speed-diatance-time thing). Am I right??

And I guess the same is the case with standard deviation operation.

I guess I conveyed what I wanted to ask properly...In other words, I just wanted to know whether there is a bizarre case in which one removes duplicates from a group of numbers and finds average and uses it as a meaningful data for further analysis....

Comment: $2.5$ km/h has physical meaning: its the average speed for the first (or last) two hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an example, namely sampling from a finite population.

Suppose you are interested in the average height of a group of people of $N$ people.  You take a sample size $n$ with replacement (e.g. choose one at random $n$ times).

The natural estimator of the group is the mean of your sample measurements, and this is an unbiased estimator.

But if you deduplicate the individuals who are sampled more than once (suppose  that measuring an individual twice gives the same answer each time and no pair of people share precisely the same height), then the sample deduplicated average will be tend to be closer to the population average than the sample average with duplicates is, especially if $n$ is large relative to $N$.

(Note: if $n=1$ there can be no duplication, and if $n=2$ then deduplicating makes no difference)

Comment: Hi Henry, in my example of car, note that the first 1 Km/hr and and the last 1 Km/hr are not exactly duplicates. They are actually different. I call them duplicates just because they are numerically equal(I mean 1 Km/hr = 1 Km/hr). But in your example, by the point "measuring an individual twice gives the same answer each time and no pair of people share precisely the same height", you are talking about counting the exact same thing more than once. But my case is not the same right?

Comment: I actually want to have two structures (List and Set) in C language. I just want to know whether it is meaning full to provide a average function to C structure set or not. For List, average function is necessary, but I am confused in case of Set.  In your example, you are sampling group of numbers(heights in your case) randomly n-times. But this not something I want.

Comment: In your car example, if you are simply measuring (possibly rounded) speeds at different times, there is unlikely to be a good reason for deduplicating.  But I was answering your final more general question

Comment: @user3219492 Also if you sampled _without_ replacement, that is, each time you measured someone's height you put them somewhere away from the rest of the population or somehow "tagged" them so that you would never measure the same person again, you would have no reason to remove duplicates. That case would be more like your driving example, where you know that the last hour is not just a re-measurement of the first hour, since we can never live the same hour of time twice.

Comment: @David Yeah, what you said will be the case of List structure in my code but not in set structure. While adding the number to a array inside Set structure, I will check whether the number is already present in the array or not. If it is already present, I won't add it. So only I thought that giving provision for average function to a set structure will be meaningless.

Comment: @user3219492 But the Set structure, applied to the height measurements taken in Henry's example, does exactly what Henry wants: it deduplicates all the measurements. So there is plenty of meaning to the average of a Set structure. You just have to know how to use it correctly. (There are plenty of ways to use the List average incorrectly too, by the way!)